If G is the INTERNAL direct product of its Sylow subgroups, then every Sylow subgroup is normal in G.
I am working on an old qualifying exam problem, which is the following:

Prove that a finite group $G$ is the internal direct product of its Sylow subgroups if and only if every Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$.

I know how to show the reverse direction:
We have the following theorem from section 5.4 of Dummit and Foote, commonly known as the Recognition Theorem:

Suppose $G$ is a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$ and $H\cap K=1$. Then $HK\cong H\times K$.

Suppose every Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$. Then $|P_{p_i}\cap P_{p_j}|=1$ for $i\neq j$. By the Recognition Theorem, $P_{p_1}P_{p_2}\ldots P_{p_n}\cong P_{p_1}\times P_{p_2}\times \ldots \times P_{p_n}$. Furthermore, $$|P_{p_1}\times P_{p_2}\times \ldots \times P_{p_n}|=|P_{p_1}||P_{p_2}|\ldots|P_{p_n}|=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{\alpha^n}=|G|.$$
Thus, $G\cong P_{p_1}P_{p_2}\ldots P_{p_n}$, as desired.

For the forward direction, it seems possible if we have a direct product instead of an internal direct product. How can we show this with an internal direct product?
Edit: Dummit and Foote defines internal direct product as follows:
If $G$ is a group and $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ with $H\cap K=1$, we call $HK$ the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$.
Does it suffice to say that the forward definition is by definition? Seems unlikely on a qualifying exam question.

You need more than $P_{p_i}\cap P_{p_j}={e}$ for $i\neq j$ to conclude that $P_{p_1}\cdots P_{p_n}\cong P_{p_1}\times\cdots\times P_{p_n}$. That implication works when you have two subgroups, but for three or more you actually need $P_{p_i}\cap \langle P_j\mid j\neq i\rangle = {1}$, which is a stronger condition. I mean, you always have $P_{p_i}\cap P_{p_j}$ trivial, but you don't always have the isomorphism. So you do not in fact have the reverse direction yet either.

Your formula for the cardinality also looks like a false generalization of the formula for two subgroups. In general it is not true that $|ABC| = \frac{|A|,|B|,|C|}{|A\cap B\cap C|}$, which certainly looks like what you are trying to use (that $|\prod_{i\in I}A_i| = \prod_{i\in I}|A_i|$ is just the definition of cardinal multiplication).

Put the information in the post, not buried in comments (i..e, state the "recognition theorem" explicitly in your post). And why don't you know that if $G$ is an internal direct product then each factor is normal? That's usually part of the definition.

@ArturoMagidin I do know that, and I agree that if G is an internal direct product then each factor is normal, but that makes the problem trivial. As a result I questioned that approach.

No, it doesn't make the problem trivial. It makes one direction trivial. So what? Often in an "if and only if" problem, one direction is much simpler than the other. And, again, why are you not putting the relevant information in the post itself, and instead want us to guess, divine, or somehow know by osmosis the correct context for your problem and question, only to later bury it in comments? That's not a good way to ask questions.

You are misapplying your theorem; the theorem is for two subgroups; you are trying to apply it for an arbitrary finite number of subgroups. You need to prove that it applies in that context as well, or argue inductively in an explicit manner.

It will be very interesting to hear what Shaun thinks.  If he doesn't know it, it's doubtful anyone else does.

Very funny, @youthinasia :D

In the product $G\times H$ the factors $G,H$ are always normal.

I know in the product GH the factors G,H are always normal. I don't think what you've written holds unless I'm misunderstanding. We can construct direct products of groups which are not normal.

It's always something obvious in the end!

By definition, @qualsqualsquals, we have $G=H\times K$ as an internal direct product iff $H, K\unlhd G$, $H\cap K={e}$, and $G=HK$.

@qualsqualsquals Oh? How so? And no, in the product $GH$ the factors are not always normal. This is highly confused.

Yes @Shaun, as in Plato's Meno.

@TedShifrin Please see the definition of internal direct product taken from Dummit and Foote included in my question

For the forward direction, one can easily see the contrapositive: if some Sylow subgroup $P$ is not normal, then $G$ cannot be the internal direct sum of its Sylow subgroups. For $P$ has a conjugate $P'$ distinct from it, and is (therefore) non trivial. If there were an internal direct product of $P$ and $P'$, that would be a subgroup of order $|P|^2$, but $|P|$ is already the highest power of some prime nuber that divides $|G|$, so this would contradict Lagrange's theorem.
